# XML Validator issue with "entity value required"

Tags: xml, dtd

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE head [
<!ENTITY header ANY >
<!ENTITY top ANY >
<!ENTITY label ANY >
<!ENTITY scope (#PCDATA) ANY >
]>
```

i don't know how to fix it.
what is the entity value??

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that it's expecting a value to appear in quotes following the `ENTITY` name.

Instead of `ENTITY`, are you sure that you aren't declaring `ELEMENT`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE head [
<!ELEMENT header ANY>
<!ELEMENT top ANY>
<!ELEMENT label ANY>
<!ELEMENT scope (#PCDATA)>
]>
```